# How to allocate SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA?

Tags: c++, winapi, struct, memory-management

[`SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff552343%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is a variable-length structure, beginning with a field containing its size followed by an array (not a pointer to one).

What is a convenient way to allocate this structure with a desired array length?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I did it like MSalters suggested:

```
std::vector<char> rawbuf(sizeof (SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA) + bufferlen);
SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA* pDIDD = 
         reinterpret_cast<SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA*>(&rawbuf[0]);
```

**Edit:**

Following Raymond Chen's example (as also discussed [on his blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/08/26/220873.aspx)) I could allocate the `SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA` structure as follows:

```
PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA pDIDD =
   malloc(FIELD_OFFSET(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA, 
                       DevicePath[bufferlen]));
```

Comment: Eh, no, that `malloc` should be matched by a `free`, but `std::unique-ptr` will call `delete`. Easier: `std::vector<char> rawbuf(sizeof (SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA) + bufferlen); SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA* ptr = reinterpret_cast<SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA*>(&rawbuf[0]);`

Comment: @MSalters: thanks for pointing that out. Can you make this an answer, then I can delete my wrong post and accept yours.

Comment: This technique provides the desired buffer size, but the question was for the desired array length. The actual size required is `FIELD_OFFSET(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA, DevicePath[arraysize])`. Note also that `std::vector<char>` only guarantees `char`-alignment, which is weaker than `SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA`-alignment. You may take an alignment fault on some processors.

Comment: @Raymond: Since the array overlaps (!) `SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA`, you have to allocate one contiguous buffer. `DevicePath[0]` is the last element of the structure _and_ the first element of the array. Therefore, the question "how to allocate the array length" should be properly interpreted. As for alignment of std::allocator, AFAICT it's a non-issue on Windows (since the `std::vector<char>` buffer is aligned there) and a non-issue everywehere else (since `SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA` is Windows-only).

Comment: Where is the guarantee that `std::vector<char>` will be aligned for arbitrary use? I can see an implementation where `std::vector<char>` uses an inline buffer if the vector is small, and falls over to the heap if the vector is large. That inline buffer may not be aligned. (And I think you missed the `[arraysize]` part of `DevicePath[arraysize]`.)